# Comparing 2 files in 2 different github repos

Tags: github, diff

Is there a way of comparing 2 files in 2 different github repos with different folder names?

```
github repo 1
a/
   1.txt

github repo 2
b/
   1.txt
```

was researching on using git diff but seems like it's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using git diff command

```
git diff --no-index repo1/a repo2/b

git diff --no-index [--options] [--] [<path>…​]
This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem. 
You can omit the --no-index option when running the command in a working
tree controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside 
the working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree 
controlled by Git.
```